# Mostrar una modal número de veces en bucle

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<?php

require 'funcs/conexion.php';

$consulta2="select descripcion from tbl_parametros where nombre = 'preguntas'";
        $result2=mysqli_query($mysqli, $consulta2);
   $hola = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
     $intentos = $hola['descripcion'];
$galletas = 0;
do {
echo "$galletas, ";

?>
```

Digamos es algo como que yo le ponga 3 al ciclo y me aparezca la modal las 3 veces, es para que responda una pregunta tantas veces

```
<?php
  $galletas++;
  } while ($galletas < $intentos);
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El código que pusiste esta medio inconcluso, pero supongo que los que queres es mostrar un modal 3 veces.

```
<?php 
$intento=1; 
while ($intento <= 3) { ?>
 (Pones aquí el javascript del modal a mostrar)
 <script> 
Alert("muestro el  intento <?php echo $intento; ?>"); 
</script> 
<?php
$intento++;
 } ?>
```

Espero esto sea lo que necesitas. En todo caso, no usarías el Alert del javascript si no un prompt .

Comment: A que te referís? Ahí no hay html.